# Cannot switch camera, doesn't work with or without release of it

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, native, release

I have an app that uses the native camera, and I need to make a video, then switch the camera, and make another one to append them. 
The issue is that if I release the camera then, when I record the second video it says: cannot call method after release(). If I don't release the camera, then when changing on the second camera it says that: Fail to connect to camera service.

This is the function to switch camera:

```
 cameraFlipButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (recording) {
                    wasrecording = true;
                }
                LogService.log(TAG, "--------------SWITCH CAMERA PRESSED");
                LogService.log(TAG, "Camera: " + mCameraDevice.getCamera().getParameters() + "camera id: " + mCameraId);
                if (mCameraId == 0) {
                    mCameraId = 1;
                    mCurrentModule.mPendingSwitchCameraId = 1;
                } else if (mCameraId == 1) {
                    mCameraId = 0;
                    mCurrentModule.mPendingSwitchCameraId = 0;
                }
                if (recording) {
                    recording = false;
                    recordButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.shutter);
                    if (timer != null) {
                        LogService.log(TAG, "---------------Timer2: " + timer);
                        timer.cancel();
                        timer.purge();
                    }
                    timer = null;
                    Handler han = new Handler();
                    han.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mCurrentModule.switchCamera();

                        }
                    }, 200);

                } else {
                    mCurrentModule.switchCamera();
                }
            }
        });
```

This is the function from my camera manager to switch the camera (mCurrentModule.switchCamera()):

```
public void switchCamera() {
    if (mPaused)
        return;

    Log.i(TAG, "MAMAMAMAMAMAM Start to switch camera. VIDEO MODULE (switchCamera)");
    mCameraId = mPendingSwitchCameraId;
    mPendingSwitchCameraId = -1;
    setCameraId(mCameraId);
    Log.i(TAG, "MAMAMAMAMAMAM after settting camera id VIDEO MODULE (switchCamera)");

    CameraHolder.instance().release();
    Log.i(TAG, "MAMAMAMAMAMAM after release VIDEO MODULE (switchCamera)");
    videoFragment.mCameraDevice = null;
    mPreviewing = false;
    Log.i(TAG, "MAMAMAMAMAMAM before open camera VIDEO MODULE (switchCamera)");
    openCamera();
    Log.i(TAG, "MAMAMAMAMAMAM after open camera VIDEO MODULE (switchCamera)");
    getDesiredPreviewSize();
    Log.i(TAG, "MAMAMAMAMAMAM after get desired size VIDEO MODULE (switchCamera)");
    startPreview();
    Log.i(TAG, "MAMAMAMAMAMAM after start preview VIDEO MODULE (switchCamera)");
    resizeForPreviewAspectRatio();
    Log.i(TAG, "MAMAMAMAMAMAM before handler VIDEO MODULE (switchCamera)");
    if (ApiHelper.HAS_SURFACE_TEXTURE) {
        // Start switch camera animation. Post a message because
        // onFrameAvailable from the old camera may already exist.
        mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(SWITCH_CAMERA_START_ANIMATION);
    }
}
```

`CameraHolder.instance().release();` from this function calls a handler to release the camera which does this:

```
public synchronized void release() {

    if (mCameraDevice == null)
        return;

    mCameraOpened = false;
    mCameraDevice.release();
    mCameraDevice = null;
    // We must set this to null because it has a reference to Camera.
    // Camera has references to the listeners.
    mParameters = null;
    mCameraId = -1;
}
```

After releasing I open the camera again:

```
public synchronized CameraProxy open(int cameraId) throws CameraHardwareException {
    // Log.i(TAG,
    // "MAMAMAMAMAMAM before release from open CAMERA HOLDER open() CameraProxy");
    if (mCameraOpened) {
        Log.i(TAG, "MAMAMAMAMAMAM before release CAMERA OPENED CAMERA HOLDER open() CameraProxy ");
        mCameraDevice.release();
    }
    if (mCameraDevice != null) {
        Log.i(TAG, "MAMAMAMAMAMAM before release from open mCameraId != cameraId CAMERA HOLDER open() CameraProxy");
        mCameraDevice.release();
        mCameraDevice = null;
        mCameraId = -1;
    }
    if (mCameraDevice == null) {
        try {
            Log.i(TAG, "MAMAMAMAMAMAM open camera " + cameraId);
            if (mMockCameraInfo == null) {
                mCameraDevice = CameraManager.instance().cameraOpen(cameraId);
            } else {
                if (mMockCamera == null)
                    throw new RuntimeException();
                mCameraDevice = mMockCamera[cameraId];
            }
            mCameraId = cameraId;
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "fail to connect Camera", e);
            throw new CameraHardwareException(e);
        }
        mParameters = mCameraDevice.getParameters();
    } else {
        try {
            mCameraDevice.reconnect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "reconnect failed.");
            throw new CameraHardwareException(e);
        }
        mCameraDevice.setParameters(mParameters);
    }
    mCameraOpened = true;
    mHandler.removeMessages(RELEASE_CAMERA);
    mKeepBeforeTime = 0;
    return mCameraDevice;
}
```

AFter this i get the size of the screen, to set the preview and etc.
After that if I press the record button again, it will crash with "cannot call method after release()". Now If I do not release, it will crash, when switching the camera because it fails to connect to the camera service. Is there a way around this?  how can i make it release the camera and still manage to record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the switch camera function, after the `openCamera();` call I initialized the recorder again, with this:

```
recorderHelper.init(videoFragment.mCameraDevice.getCamera(), mPreviewSurfaceView.getHolder());
```

And now it works, I manage to change the camera and record.